# How do I compare values from same column and different row but same table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get records where startdate is different for specific account Name. I have below sample data.

Sample data script as below

```
create table Meter (AccountNumer varchar(50), MeterNumber varchar(50), StartDate date)
Insert into Meter Values('0142628117','123470203','4/22/2020')
Insert into Meter Values('0142628117','123470205','4/22/2020')
Insert into Meter Values('0160059948','100094717','4/24/2020')
Insert into Meter Values('0160059948','328144931','4/24/2020')
Insert into Meter Values('0500000178767001363445','TCA105238304','10/2/2018')
Insert into Meter Values('0500000178767001363445','TCA130359929','8/12/2019')
Insert into Meter Values('0500071816677001432356','1ND386803501','8/20/2019')
Insert into Meter Values('0500071816677001432356','99D024666064','7/18/2019')


RowNo   AccountNumber           MeterNumber     StartDate
    1   0500000178767001363445  TCA105238304    10/2/2018
    2   0500000178767001363445  TCA130359929    8/12/2019
    3   0160059948              100094717       4/24/2020
    4   0160059948              328144931       4/24/2020
    5   0500071816677001432356  1ND386803501    8/20/2019
    6   0500071816677001432356  99D024666064    7/18/2019
    7   0142628117              123470203       4/22/2020
    8   0142628117              123470205       4/22/2020
```

I am trying to get just records where start date are different for account number (both rows). so the result I am expecting as below for above table.

Expected result

```
RowNo   AccountNumber           MeterNumber     StartDate
    1   0500000178767001363445  TCA105238304    10/2/2018
    2   0500000178767001363445  TCA130359929    8/12/2019
    5   0500071816677001432356  1ND386803501    8/20/2019
    6   0500071816677001432356  99D024666064    7/18/2019
```

any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: `from Meter m1 where exists (select * from Meter m2 where m2.accountnumber = m1.accountnumber and m2.startdate <> m1.startdate)`?

Comment: Thanks @GSerg.. this is working exactly as i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below query

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY m.AccountNumer)RowNo    , m.AccountNumer,m.MeterNumber,m.StartDate 
from meter m
INNER JOIN meter n ON m.AccountNumer=n.AccountNumer
and m.StartDate <> n.StartDate
```

Let me know in case you face any issue or any change is required.

Comment: I have some question on the same kind of requirement, I have create another post for that question. you might be able to answer quick as you are already aware of this scenario. could you please look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025222/how-do-i-get-record-with-maxdate-and-then-compare-values-to-get-result

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this.

We just partition the results by `AccountNumber` and check that the maximum and minimum `StartDate` per partition is different.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      MinDate = MIN(m.StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY m.AccountNumber),
      MaxDate = MAX(m.StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY m.AccountNumber)
    FROM Meter m
) m
WHERE MinDate <> MaxDate;
```

Comment: I have some question on the same kind of requirement, I have create another post for that question. you might be able to answer quick as you are already aware of this scenario. could you please look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025222/how-do-i-get-record-with-maxdate-and-then-compare-values-to-get-result