# How do I get record with Max(date) and then compare values to get result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get record with Max(StartDate) for each MeterNumber and then try to get records where startdate, enddate & RateCode is different for specific AccountNumber.

Sample data script as below

```
create table Meter 
(
    AccountNumer varchar(50), 
    MeterNumber varchar(50), 
    StartDate date, 
    EndDate date, 
    RateCode Varchar(50)
)

Insert into Meter Values('0142628117','123470203','4/22/2020','12/31/9999','UGE-PECO-E-R-V-GRN-HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20')
Insert into Meter Values('0142628117','123470203','4/10/2019', '4/9/2020', '***Custom***')
Insert into Meter Values('0142628117','123470205','4/22/2020','12/31/9999','UGE-PECO-E-R-V-GRN-HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20')
Insert into Meter Values('0142628117','123470205','4/10/2019', '4/9/2020', '***Custom***')
    
Insert into Meter Values('0500000178767001363445','TCA105238304','02/25/2016','04/22/2016', '***Custom***')
Insert into Meter Values('0500000178767001363445','TCA105238304','10/2/2018','08/11/2019', '***Custom***')
Insert into Meter Values('0500000178767001363445','TCA130359929','8/12/2019','12/31/9999', '***Custom***')

RowNo   AccountNumer            MeterNumber     StartDate   EndDate     RateCode
    1   0142628117              123470203       2020-04-22  9999-12-31  UGE-PECO-E-R-V-GRN-HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20
    2   0142628117              123470203       2019-04-10  2020-04-09  ***Custom***
    3   0142628117              123470205       2020-04-22  9999-12-31  UGE-PECO-E-R-V-GRN-HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20
    4   0142628117              123470205       2019-04-10  2020-04-09  ***Custom***
    5   0500000178767001363445  TCA105238304    2016-02-25  2016-04-22  ***Custom***
    6   0500000178767001363445  TCA105238304    2018-10-02  2019-08-11  ***Custom***
    7   0500000178767001363445  TCA130359929    2019-08-12  9999-12-31  ***Custom***
```

First I need to find `Max(StartDate)` for each `MeterNumber` for specific `AccountNumber`. Output should be like this:

```
    RowNo   AccountNumer            MeterNumber        StartDate   EndDate     RateCode
        1   0142628117              123470203       2020-04-22  9999-12-31  UGE-PECO-E-R-V-GRN-HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20
        3   0142628117              123470205       2020-04-22  9999-12-31  UGE-PECO-E-R-V-GRN-HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20
        6   0500000178767001363445  TCA105238304    2018-10-02  2019-08-11  ***Custom***
        7   0500000178767001363445  TCA130359929    2019-08-12  9999-12-31  ***Custom***
```

And then I am trying to get just records where start date, end date and ratecode are **different** for account number from the (both rows). so the final result I am expecting as below for above table.

```
   RowNo   AccountNumer            MeterNumber        StartDate   EndDate     RateCode
       6    0500000178767001363445  TCA105238304    2018-10-02  2019-08-11  ***Custom***
       7    0500000178767001363445  TCA130359929    2019-08-12  9999-12-31  ***Custom***
```

Any help will be really appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 3 step process, first rank your records for each Account/Meter combination using ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT *,
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber, MeterNumber 
                                    ORDER BY EndDate DESC)
FROM Meter
```

**OUTPUT**

| AccountNumber | MeterNumber | StartDate | EndDate | RateCode | RowNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0142628117 | 123470203 | 2020-04-22 | 9999-12-31 | ETF0_APR20 | 1 |
| 0142628117 | 123470203 | 2019-04-10 | 2020-04-09 | ***Custom*** | 2 |
| 0142628117 | 123470205 | 2020-04-22 | 9999-12-31 | ETF0_APR20 | 1 |
| 0142628117 | 123470205 | 2019-04-10 | 2020-04-09 | ***Custom*** | 2 |
| 1363445 | 105238304 | 2018-10-02 | 2019-08-11 | ***Custom*** | 1 |
| 1363445 | 105238304 | 2016-02-25 | 2016-04-22 | ***Custom*** | 2 |
| 1363445 | 130359929 | 2019-08-12 | 9999-12-31 | ***Custom*** | 1 |

<sub>*N.B. Some data shortened to display better*</sub>

Then you can filter for were RowNumber = 1 to get the latest end date for each meter.

Next you need to count the distinct EndDate/RateCode combinations, you can't use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`  in a windowed function, however you can emulate this using `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT *,
        CntDistinct = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
                                                ORDER BY EndDate, RateCode) 
                        + DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
                                            ORDER BY EndDate DESC, RateCode DESC) - 1
FROM (  SELECT *,
                RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber, MeterNumber 
                                                ORDER BY EndDate DESC)
        FROM Meter AS m
    ) AS m
WHERE m.RowNumber = 1;
```

**OUTPUT**

| AccountNumber | MeterNumber | StartDate | EndDate | RateCode | CntDistinct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0142628117 | 123470203 | 2020-04-22 | 9999-12-31 | ETF0_APR20 | 1 |
| 0142628117 | 123470205 | 2020-04-22 | 9999-12-31 | ETF0_APR20 | 1 |
| 1363445 | 130359929 | 2019-08-12 | 9999-12-31 | ***Custom*** | 2 |
| 1363445 | 105238304 | 2018-10-02 | 2019-08-11 | ***Custom*** | 2 |

<sub>*N.B. Some data shortened to display better*</sub>

Finally put all this into a further subquery and limit to where there is more than one unique combination of EndDate/RateCode:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, MeterNumber, StartDate, EndDate, RateCode
FROM (  SELECT *,
                CntDistinct = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
                                                    ORDER BY EndDate, RateCode) 
                                + DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
                                                    ORDER BY EndDate DESC, RateCode DESC) - 1
            FROM (  SELECT *,
                            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber, MeterNumber 
                                                        ORDER BY EndDate DESC)
                    FROM Meter AS m
                ) AS m
            WHERE m.RowNumber = 1
    ) AS m
WHERE m.CntDistinct > 1;
```

**OUTPUT**

| AccountNumber | MeterNumber | StartDate | EndDate | RateCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0500000178767001363445 | TCA105238304 | 2018-10-02 | 2019-08-11 | ***Custom*** |
| 0500000178767001363445 | TCA130359929 | 2019-08-12 | 9999-12-31 | ***Custom*** |

**[Example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d19fb1482291ec9de18251d54022550)**

Comment: This is perfect solution. Thank you for saving my day @GarethD :)